# How can I avoid this "variable used within its own initial value" error?

Tags: swift

### Update:

This is an attempt to improve this question. I have a solution, which I will post as an answer shortly.  Its based on the comments I received below.  Hopefully this improvement, along with the comments and subsequent answer, can help someone else who might fall into the same trap I did.

---

I have a collection of objects that need to download some images before I consider them "ready".

I attempted to handle this by passing in a "completion handler" into the init function, which I in turn would pass it to the completion handler of the function that would actually download the images.  The intended net result being that after the object was initialized **and** loaded with it's images, then the closure I passed in during initialization would be called, in this case a notification that the object was "ready"

To accomplish this I tried to capture the newly created object in the closure passed in as the completion handler.  (shown below in trailing closure format)

```
for marker in markerList {
  var ourLatitudeMapMarker = OurLatitudeMapMarker(size: size) {
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("OurLatitudeMapMarkerReady", object: self, userInfo: ["ourLatitudeMapMarker":ourLatitudeMapMarker])
   }
}
```

This results in the error "variable used within its own initial value".

My original, poorly phrased question,  was essentially:

How can I get the newly created object into the completion handler passed to the init function so that it can be used in the completion handler when the object finally, is "ready"

In hindsight I think my question should have been:

How can I call a closure when my objects are "ready"?  "ready" being initialized and loaded with their images.

Comment: You could pass the object in as an argument to the completion block.

Comment: excellent.  I have not tested it but it does compile

Comment: Can I strongly urge against writing these sorts of constructors?  Please, please don't do this...

Comment: An initializer should initialize with as light a touch as possible, hopefully without anything that can fail and certainly without making network calls. Just initialize all properties to constants or passed in values. IOW just initialize.

Comment: so you would suggest something like a simple initializer and then maybe a load images method that takes the completion block?

Comment: I ended up just moving all the code in the init to a loadimages method, the init is now 1 line (I need to initialize one property).  Looks and feels much better! Thanks for the suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As jtbandes pointed out in his comment,  one solution to this could have been to simply pass self in as an argument to the the completion handler,  but in the end I agreed with both nhgrif's and zaph's comments.

The solution was obvious, once I realized that being initialized and being ready are not the same thing.  So I just have init, **initialize**  the object and another method loadImages,  takes the completion handler, which is passes to the method that actually down loads the images, and calls the completion handler when the objects are ready.

So now instead of one statement that attempted to do everything (initialize and load the images),  I have two.

```
let ourLatitudeMapMarker = OurLatitudeMapMarker(size: size)
```

and then later do something like this

```
ourLatitudeMapMarker.loadImages() {
      NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("OurLatitudeMapMarkerReady", object: self, userInfo: ["ourLatitudeMapMarker":ourLatitudeMapMarker])
}
```